# Reusing bean definitions in Spring

Tags: java, xml, spring

Our project has two application contexts:

- application-context.xml
- application-context-test.xml

Currently each file has duplicate bean definitions. So for example the following bean would be in each application context:

```
<bean id="foo "class="com.foo">
     <property name="bar">
          <ref local="bar"/>
     </property>
</bean>
```

The plan is to create another file for bean definitions so we can reuse the beans, however, if we put the above xml segment into its own file, there will be no reference to `bar`

Is there an easy way to solve this?

Please note that `bar`will be different in each application context.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<ref local="bar"/>` has a specific meaning - it means that `bar` must be defined *in the same file*. In your case, that's too strict, so loosen it a bit:

```
<bean id="foo "class="com.foo">
     <property name="bar" ref="bar"/>
</bean>
```

And then use `<import resource="...">` to import this file where needed.

With this, `bar` must still exist, but it can be in any file that's part of the context, or in any of the parent contexts.

Comment: Ahh! overlooked "local". Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Sure, use a common context file that you import into both xml files.

```
<import resource="/common"/>
```

See [4.2.2.1. Composing XML-based configuration metadata](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-xml-import)